# Call to undefined method AcceptanceTester::amOnPage

Tags: php, codeception

I have a generated class:

```
<?php

class DefaultCest
{
    public function _before(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
    }

    public function _after(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
    }

    // tests
    public function tryToTest(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $I->amOnPage('/');
    }
}
```

and I added method

```
$I->amOnPage('/')
```

as shown in the examples in documentation.

But this method does not exist. I do not get why? Php storm autocompletes only

```
am()
```

and

```
amGoingTo()
```

methods when I type

```
$I->am
```

And of course I am getting that error.

What can be wrong there, why there is no method amOnPage() ?

**Update:**

acceptance.suite.yml

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - \Helper\Acceptance
        - PhpBrowser:
            url: 127.0.0.1:8000
```

Comment: What modules are enabled in `acceptance.suite.yml`?

Comment: @Naktibalda - updated question

Comment: That error is only possible if PhpBrowser is not enabled. Random suggestion: run `codecept build` - does it help? does it show that PhpBrowser is included to AcceptanceTester?

Comment: @Naktibalda - it helped, thanks :) did not even check 2nd question